# Mongoose - How to Specify and Delete Dependent Relations?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

With MongoDB and Mongoose, How can I mark objects as dependent on their relations so that if the Parent object is deleted, all of the children objects dependent on it will be deleted as well.  For instance, how can I have all articles by an author be automatically deleted if the author is deleted?

```
var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
});

var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    author: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Author'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like mysql's "foreign key on delete cascade" where if you delete a parent, children are automatically deleted, then it is not possible in pure mongodb.

In order to achieve this, you have to implement it in your application logic. When you delete an author you have to run another delete on the article collection based on the authorID. Do not forget to put an index on this field.

Comment: thanks... @Salvador. I somehow missed the index part. btw, you have 4725 views in next 1yr 2 months. May be because of your reputation or the picture. :)